# Can't change text color(label) in bottomNavigationBarTheme dart & flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Can't change the text color in bottomNavigationBarTheme(unselectedLabelStyle and selectedLabelStyle).
I'm writing correctly, if I change the font size, everything works, but if I change the text, it doesn't work.[image: How I change font color and size in selectedLabelStyle and unselectedLabelStyle TextStyle]

Tried changing colors, updated flutter and dart

Comment: can you include a full sample widget as code-snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `selectedItemColor` and `unselectedItemColor` instead.

> The color of the (un)selected BottomNavigationBarItem.icon and BottomNavigationBarItem.label.

If a different color is required for icons use `(un)selectedIconTheme`. Something like this:

```
const BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
  showSelectedLabels: true,
  showUnselectedLabels: true,
  selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
  unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
  selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
  unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey),
),
```